Why is there no response when clicking "new" after opening the jupter notebook and jumping to the homepage?
And it will automatically check the first folder.How should I solve this problem?I downloaded Anaconda again, but the problem still persists.
I am a programming novice.I have searched for a lot of information on various websites, but I have not been able to solve it. I hope someone who is skilled can help me!!!
